# While pushing splitted bitbucket repo it complains about committer is different from pusher

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

I'm following https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/split-a-repository-in-two-313464964.html to split a directory into another bitbucket repo.

As described in the above link, there's a repo called splitpractice which has three directories:

- bigdir
- lildir
- lildir2

The goal is to move bigdir to a new repo called freshrepo while keeping the commit history. I've followed all the steps, in the last step I need to push the code to freshrepo. Since there are commits from different users, bitbucket complains that it does not allow pusher to be different from committer with the following message:

> remote: refs/heads/master: 2e462cc80379851e33645ae86907951f412f0688: expected committer name 'My name(pusher)' but found 'Actual Committer'
>
> Committer(s) email address is not a valid Bitbucket email address, email address needs to be the same as the Pusher email address.

Or

> Committer(s) is not a valid Bitbucket user, Committer(s) need to be the same as Pusher.
>
> Make sure your local git installation is using your credentials by running "git config --global -l"

Is there any work around for this?
Or am I following the right process? Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does all committers have an bitbucket account ? Does the name given with `git show 2e462cc80379851e33645ae86907951f412f0688` match your bitbucket account ?

Comment: Are you using BB Cloud documentation for something on BB Server?

Comment: There are some inactive accounts as well but in my case, my name matches my account. I’m using BB Cloud documentation for BB Server.